# laravel - run a task after a queue finish all its jobs

Tags: php, laravel

I need to run a task for a list that can reach thousands of items.

To avoid a single job running for a long time, I've created a job to enqueue all items.

The problem is that I need to run another task before and after that queue gets done.

The solution I see is to use delays:

```
$schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\PauseSystem())     ->hourly('00:01');
$schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\EnqueueAllItems()) ->hourly('00:02'); // adds all items as separated job in a queue
$schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\ReopenSystem())    ->hourly('55:00');
```

This way I have the time between `00:02` and `55:00` to ensure all items have been completed.

It looks not safe and maybe causes job overlapping.

Is there any safer way to run a task after a queue finish all its jobs?

Comment: Why don't you trigger job from other dependent job. Trigger JobB from at the end of JobA and JobC at then end of JobB

Comment: @Ersoy because item tasks are enqueued to run in parallel. it's not a single job -- jobB is adding many smaller jobs to the queue

Comment: I think you are don't know when all jobs in the `EnqueueAllItems` done. I think you can set a cache key for each jobs in EnqueueAllItems, mark it done when a single job done. Then in ReopenSystem, you can loop each single cache value of all the jobs to check they're completed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned there are parallel and multiple jobs, here is how we solved a similar issue. We have a reporting system to prepare a report from multiple customers. There were more than 1000 customers.

- Each `ReportPusher` job was responsible for a single customer
- In this job we were getting report from different databases and pushing all the data to a bucket(redis list).
- If all the jobs(%99 of the jobs sometimes) are completed to work, another `ReportCollector` job should do its work.
- Gets all the data from the single bucket, formats, creates an excel and sends an email. - This collector job has to run after all the `ReportPusher` jobs completed.

Here how we did;

- Trigger all `ReportPusher` jobs at the same time
- Set total number of triggered jobs in some place (redis key for example) `$total`
- Trigger `ReportCollector` n minutes later (it could be 15 minutes)
- Each `ReportPusher` jobs increments another key when they complete their process `$incremented`
- 15 Minutes later when `ReportCollector` works, do these;

  - If `total` equals to `incremented count` let ReportCollector does it work
  - If not, trigger the same job with t delay(you decide) + incremented attempt
  - After n attempts(you decide) if the counts still don't match(the %99 i mentioned above) calculate the report.

This fallback policy is to prevent total failure if there is a mistake in one/two of the customers. We don't wont to throw all the calculated data(%99 of the customers) just because of one/two customers. You may put some alert/error tracking system to fix corrupted data later.